# get string from a dll inside another dll

Tags: c++, c, string, loadlibrary

Here is the case:

I made a dll with a function1 inside as below:

```
int function1( char *inVal, char *outVal)
{
....
strcpy(outVal,dn.commonname.c_str());
}
```

in the last line outVal is pointed to dn.commonname which is a string.

I loaded this dll in another dll with LoadLibrary successfully. In second dll I have:

```
int function1(string inval, string &outVal)
{   
    typedef int (WINAPI *func1Ptr)(char *, char *);


        char outValPtr[128] = {0};
        int retVal = func1Lnk((char *)inVal.c_str(), outValPtr);
        string outVal = outValPtr;  
 }
```

Now, I am loading second dll in my code and call fnuction1, but when I check the second argument of the function, I get NULL.

Can anyone shed the light on this?

**EDIT-1**

I changed my code to:

```
int function1(string inVal, string &outVal)
{   
    typedef int (WINAPI *func1Ptr)(char *, char *);


        char outValPtr[128] = {0};
        int retVal = func1Lnk((char *)inVal.c_str(), outValPtr);
        outVal = outValPtr;  
 }
```

But the problem did not solve. any clue?

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a local variable shadowing the argument:

```
string outVal = outValPtr;
```

Well, it's *almost* shadowing the argument, because the spelling of the names are different. A variable named `outVal` is not the same variable as one named `outval`. Names in C++ are case-dependent.

Comment: so how should I pass the value to argument?

Comment: I see a lowercase v and an uppercase V, so I don't think he does, actually. But he doesn't set the lowercase V one to anything so basically you're sorta wrong but still right. :)

Comment: @Amir Just assign to the argument, you don't need the local variable.

Comment: @amir change 'string outVal =' to 'outval ='

Comment: @Amir Use a debugger to step though the code to see that everything looks good. Also you should make sure that the string copied in the DLL is no longer than 127 characters.